# Custom Github Action if: cancelled() would not run when workflow is cancelled

Tags: github-actions

## Goal

I am building a custom github action that will execute various long-running tasks on a remote machine through a powershell script: `main.ps1`

In the event that the Github Action workflow is cancelled manually by the user, I want to be able to send a few commands to stop those long running tasks so they stop consuming
resources, these commands are stored in `cancelJob.ps1`

Here is my `action.yml`:

```
name: Custom Github Action
description: 'this is a custom github action'
branding:
  icon: check-circle
  color: blue
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Main Step
      run: |
        ${{ github.action_path }}/main.ps1
      shell: pwsh
    - name: Run only if workflow is cancelled
      run: |
        ${{ github.action_path }}/cancelJob.ps1
      if: cancelled() 
      shell: pwsh
```

## Problem

In my main workflow, I tested running my custom Github Action and the "Main Step" works well. However, when I then try to cancel the workflow midway through the "Main Step", the second step "Run only if workflow is cancelled" does not run despite having `if: cancelled()`

Here is a screenshot of the log:
[image]
It seems like the step is recognized, but it wouldn't run.

## Question

How do I get the second step "Run only if workflow is cancelled" to run in the event of a user cancelling the workflow?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using [`runs.post`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runspost) or [`runs.post-if`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runspost-if) instead for cleanup?

Comment: Looks like you have another step running with `if: always()` which is not cancellable, is it the case?

Comment: @Azeem run.post seems to be used for Javascript actions, while what I want to run are powershell scripts which I resorted to using composite actions instead. If run.post is the only to go, does that mean I need to convert my scripts to Javascript?

Comment: @Fcmam5 That is correct, I also have another if: always() for testing purposes, would that interfere with my if: cancelled() step?

Comment: @mephesis: Yes, `runs.post` or `runs.post-if` work with JavaScript actions. There is this [`runs.post-entrypoint`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runspost-entrypoint) for Docker container actions but I'm not sure if that would serve your purpose. BTW, did you try running multiple runs and canceling them at various points to see if it was some timing issue while canceling?